# Python - watermark superimposed

Tags: python, image

In Python 3x, my aim is to superimpose a PIL (ver 5.1) type RGBA image onto a greyscale image:

```
from PIL import Image

layer1 = Image.open("lena.jpg")  
layer2 = Image.open("watermark.png")              

canvas = Image.new("RGBA", layer1.size, (0,0,0,0))
canvas.paste(layer1)
canvas.paste(layer2, (int(layer1.width/2.2), int(layer1.height/1.8)), layer2)
canvas.show()
```

This looks like it works but is the A-channel transparency accounted for?
In this instance, layer2 (RGBA) is always much smaller than layer1 (greyscale).

From my understanding, using the paste method in older versions of PIL (ver 3.1) didn't account for the alpha channel, but the newer one (ver 5) does? from the docs:

*If a mask is given, this method updates only the regions indicated by the mask. You can use either “1”, “L” or “RGBA” images (in the latter case, the alpha band is used as mask). Where the mask is 255, the given image is copied as is. Where the mask is 0, the current value is preserved. Intermediate values will mix the two images together, including their alpha channels if they have them.*

[image]

Comment: If you can't tell by looking at the image, why not test the same code with a much larger and much more transparent image, which should make it a lot more obvious whether it's doing the right thing?

Comment: Anyway, when I test this with a large circle that's 80% alpha, it definitely is transparent for me. (Although I might use `alpha_composite` or `ImageChops` to do this, so instead of silently doing the wrong thing on old versions of Pillow it either works or fails noisily.)

Comment: many thanks abarnert, yes I had considered alpha_composite but how do you set the location of the second/pasted image? also, the source and dst images have to be the same size under alpha_composite I think(?)

Comment: Well, they don't have to be the same size, but if they aren't, the smaller one will just end up in the upper-left corner. So you need to do it in two steps—first resize `layer2` to the size of `layer1` by expanding it equally in all directions, and then composite them. It's definitely not as simple as pasting; it just has the advantage of working correctly with old versions. If I were building a SaaS solution, I wouldn't worry about that; if I were building a library for other devs, and had no other reason to require 5.0+, I would; etc.

Comment: ah, yes of course - but how do I resize layer2 without altering originally attributes (e.g. could be a text watermark or something similar). I'm not using old versions (unless version PIL version 5x is old?) - so does that mean the paste method is ok?